# JMeter - Single Page Application - Blazor Application - Web socket connections - Service stack authentication

Tags: websocket, jmeter, single-page-application

I have to perform client End Load testing for Single Page application - Blazor server technology which uses Narrum services with Service stack authentication. When tried to record application with JMeter and Blaze meter, I can see only few http requests that to only GET requests. I can't see any session Id's or authentication details like the provided User name and Passwords in those requests. Can any one please suggest whether I need to add the web socket connection explicitly using Web socket sampler to the recorded script or any other suitable tool that can be used for this application Client-End performance?
Thanks in advance...

I have tried recording with JMeter, Blazemeter. Also converting Har file to JMX. But no where I can find connection requests. In developer tools observed WSS requests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE1u7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ6YJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

As it evidenced by its name JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is only capable of recording [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS) requests. Same applies to BlazeMeter, current version of Chrome Extension won't record WebSocket traffic. You can [submit a feature request](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005740049-Submitting-Feature-Requests-Ideas) for the latter one.

[WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) is a different protocol and I'm not aware of any existing JMeter plugin which is capable of recording this type of traffic.

In the meantime you can work it around as follows: you can capture the network footprint of the real browser using either your browser developer tools or 3rd-party sniffer like Fiddler or Wireshark. Once you identify which WebSocket requests does browser send you can use i.e. **[JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)** plugin to simulate these requests with JMeter.

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right tool for your needs?  You have a complex application running substantial client sode JavaScript code that is reversing the concept of client and server to have notifications sent to the client.   perhaps you might consider a model that runs full browsers so you can inherit a lot of capability that you need?